# Is it possible to output an RGB document with JSPDF

Tags: javascript, rgb, jspdf, cmyk

I'm using [JSPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) to generate a PDF. Currently the output pdf has a CMYK colour space, but I need it to be RGB.

I've hunted through the docs but I can see no way of changing the output document's colour space.

Is this possible?

I'm creating the document like this, and looking at the source, these are all the supported options other than `compress`.

```
   this.doc = new jsPDF({
      unit: 'mm',
      orientation: 'portrait',
      format: [width, height],
      lineHeight: 1.2
    })
```

I then save the doc using:

```
this.doc.save(this.writePath);
```

Which takes only a single argument.

I don't see any way to change the colour mode of the output PDF.

Comment: When you take a look on this [file](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/jspdf.js), you can choose between rgb and cmyk by providing either 3 or 4 parameter with the setDrawColor and setFillColor methods. This can be used to draw something but when an image is used you have to convert its color-space before printing it in a pdf. This [doc](http://kickstartonline.co.uk/admina/doc/symbols/jsPDF.html) tells the same.

Comment: @Blauharley That's drawing. I'm talking about the document color mode which can be either RGB or CMYK.